# Looking for a Powershell Script to check if Volume Shadow Copy is enabled

Tags: powershell

Sorry for asking, new in PowerShell. Looking for a Powershell Script to check if Volume Shadow Copy is enabled.
Couldn't find any useful and functional script.

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then edit your question tnx

Comment: Did you at least try to search for it with your favorite search engine? [Powershell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/)

Answer (score 2):

Where did you look?
There are a number samples of these all over the web.

For example, using the script downloadable from here:

> Get Shadow Copy Statistics
>
> If you use Shadow Copies of Shared Folders (Previous Versions), this
>   script may help you keep on eye on how much history you have, the
>   average snapshot size, whether you are hitting storage area limits or
>   the 64 shadow copies per volume limit.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Shadow-Copy-Statistics-79e05a57

You can use it's example to get stats of such items. Meaning, if you get any results, then of course it's enabled.

```
#Query the local machine 
.\Get-ShadowCopyStats.ps1 -ServerName . 

#Query a remote machine 
.\Get-ShadowCopyStats.ps1 -ServerName FS01 

#Query multiple remote machines by passing an array 
.\Get-ShadowCopyStats.ps1 -ServerName FS01,FS02 

#Since it's the first parameter, you don't have to include -ServerName in the command: 
.\Get-ShadowCopyStats.ps1 FS01,FS02 

#Query multiple remote machines by passing them to the script down the pipeline 
"FS01","FS02" | .\Get-ShadowCopyStats.ps1

Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Servers,DC=company,DC=tld" | .\Get-ShadowCopyStats.ps1 -ShowAllVolumes | Tee-Object -Variable ShadowCopyStats 
$ShadowCopyStats | Select * | Export-Csv -NoTypeInformation .\ShadowCopyStats.csv
```

Or this one...

> Get Remote Shadow Volume Information With Powershell
>
> Gather the remote shadow volume information for one or more systems
>   using wmi, alternate credentials, and multiple runspaces. Function
>   supports custom timeout parameters in case of wmi problems and returns
>   shadow volume information, shadow copies, their providers, and
>   settings.
>
> https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/Get-Remote-Shadow-Volume-e5a72619

```
RemoteShadowCopyInformation -ComputerName 'Server2' -Credential $cred).ShadowCopyVolumes
```

Answer (score 0):

when the shadowcopy is enabled, there will be a scheduled task created

```
$allTasks = Get-ScheduledTask
foreach ($task in $allTasks) {
    if ($task.TaskName.Contains("ShadowCopyVolume")) {

        #get volumeid & drive letter which shadowcopy is enabled
        $allVolumes = Get-Volume
        foreach ($volume in $allVolumes) {
            if ($volume.ObjectId.Contains(($task.TaskName.Split("{")[1]).Split("}")[0])) {
                write-host ($volume.driveletter + ":\ is enabled")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: script to check if shadowcopy is enabled]

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.